# Arrange legends plotly

Tags: python, plotly, legend, pie-chart, plotly-python

I want to arrange the legend for my pie chart which I have built using plotly, by default it arranges the legend having the highest distribution first and with lower distribution after it, but i want them in a specific order as per project requirement. As per the image I want 80+ to be on top then 61-80 then 41-60, then 21-40 then 11-20 then below 21 being the last. Can anyone help me with this.[image]

Comment: Check this https://plotly.com/python/reference/#layout-legend-traceorder

Comment: @alec_djinn this does not work because it is just arranging the default into reversed or grouped order, I want it to be in order as I mentioned in the question

Comment: Please show your code, I need to be able to reproduce your plot to help

Answer (score 2):

- below shows unordered and ordered
- to order, sort dataframe used to generate pie and `sort=False`

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import plotly.express as px

cats = ["80+", "61-80", "41-60", "21-40", "11-20", "below 21"]

df = pd.DataFrame(
    {"cat": np.random.choice(cats, 100), "refer": np.random.randint(1, 50, 100)}
)

px.pie(
    df,
    values="refer",
    names="cat",
).show()

px.pie(
    df.sort_values(by="cat", key=lambda s: s.map({k: i for i, k in enumerate(cats)})),
    values="refer",
    names="cat",
).update_traces(sort=False).show()
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

There's a very simple and straightforward solution for this just arrange the values in a DataFrame and call the pie chart function from plotly.graph_objects.